# Sorting inside a file

Tags: java, html, file, jsp, tomcat

I have a txt file with strings containing integers.
I want to copy it to some container (I tried using ArrayList), sort it and write in another file.

Here is what I did (this code is part of my servlet):

```
String path = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                    + "numbers.txt";
            String path2 = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                    + "numbers2.txt";

            ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            String eachLine = br.readLine();
            while (eachLine != null) {
            arr.add(Integer.parseInt(eachLine));
            eachLine = br.readLine();
            }
            filereader.close();  

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path2, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
                writer.write(arr.get(i) + "-");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
```

However it never works: problem is that new file is always empty, nothing is written inside of it, that's the problem.

Comment: Please define "it never works". What do you get instead of a sorted file?

Comment: I also don't see you call any sort code thus I assume you get the same order as before, don't you?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the input file contents are read and parsed properly?

Answer (score 3):

There is no attempt to sort the `ArrayList` and the order of an `ArrayList` will be the order in which elements were added.

To sort the `ArrayList` use `java.util.Collections.sort()`:

```
Collections.sort(arr); // Ascending order.
```

There is another version of `Collections.sort()` that accepts a `Comparator` to define the order if ascending order is not suitable.

Comment: it never works: problem is that new file is always empty, nothing is written inside of it, that's the problem.

Comment: can you check (print somewhere) `arr.size()` to ensure something was read and `arr` is populated?

Comment: The [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) for `getRealPath()` does not indicate if a trailing slash is appended to the returned string, and I don't know if this is the case or not. Can you check the paths to the files that being used?